# Export TexCoord json in meshlab

Tags: json, textures, meshlab

I am new to to the 3d world, i wonder why in the "Export Mesh as" screen in meshlab i cannot export with "TexCoord" my mesh, i cannot select the checkbox, it shows only "Color" and "Normal" options under the "Vert" option.

I've imported the mesh from a 3d scanned .OBJ and .MTL, it renders ok but i cannot export with "TexCoord" that i need in my resulting JSON file to render in a gl view in another application.

There's any operations can i do on my mesh to get the things work? In another example JSON export i see in the JSON the `texcoord_buffer` property that i need to show properly the texture.

Answer (score 0):

found. you have to go in filters > texture > per vertex texture function